# confusion in url and template in django

Tags: python, django

My url is :

```
1. http://localhost:8000/docs/[slug]
2. http://localhost:8000/docs/[slug]/login
```

`1`. url calls before number `2. url` I want to send 
the `slug` value to the function mapped by the `url 2.` In template 
what should i wrote for form action event.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/login/$', login),
    (r'^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', slug),

Comment: Please make it more explicit...

Comment: -1: Incomprehensible.  Please **update** the question with the actual code.  Please do not post code in a comment. Please **update** the question with the relevant lines from the actual `urls.py` file.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, this is nearly incomprehensible, but I'm going to give it a go in terms of an answer.

In terms of calling sequence, there is none. A user might first visit url `2` or url `1`. You have no way of guaranteeing which they will try to access first because they might directly input the url into their browser. The only thing you can do is set a variable in `request.session`'s dict and test for it with your `login` url.

In terms of passing `slug` to another url, if you're having a url with this in it:

```
urls = ('',
url(r'docs/(?P<slug>\w+)', 'app.views.slug', name='slug-view'),
url(r'docs/(?P<slug>\w+)/login', 'app.views.slug_login', name='slug-login'),
#..
)
```

Then in your template you can do this:

```
<form action="{% url slug-login slugname %}" method="POST">
```

Your views.py would look something like this.

```
def slug(request, slug):
    #
    #

    return render_to_response('templatename.html', {'slugname':slug}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def slug_login(request, slug):
    # do something with slug.
```

This way, when you access the slug view, you pass into the template a variable called slugname, which the template uses with django's url library to resolve a specifically named url in urls.py with one named parameter, slug, which it will assign the value of slugname.

I suggest you try it.

I might also reccoment you read up on the [django url dispatcher](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/). Your use of regex without named parameters is acceptable but really not best practice. I'd also suggest [django shortcuts (render_to_response)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/) as a quick way to pass variables into templates and the [django template language](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) itself.